# How to compute P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c)?

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation, conditional-expectation

Consider the discrete random variable $Y$, the continuous random variable $X$, and a constant $c$. The goal is to find $$P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c),$$
when we are only given $P(y)$, function $h(y)$, and $P(|X-h(y)| < c|Y=y)$ for all possible values of y in domain of Y.

**UPDATE**: I have tried to write $P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c)$ based on density function of $f(x,y)$ but this didn't get me so much far as the boundaries of integral doesn't let me to take the summation inside :
$$P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c) = \sum_y\int_{-c+E_Y[h(y)]}^{c+E_Y[h(y)]}f(x,y)dx$$

Comment: $P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c) = \sum_{z \in R_Y} P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c | Y = z) P(Y = z)$, right?

Comment: Yes. But we don't know  $P(|X - E_Y[h(y)]| < c | Y = z)$.

Comment: Oh, I misread!, sorry.

Comment: @Julian, yes, but $h(y) \neq \mathsf E(h(Y))$, so we don't have enough to go further.

Comment: I think the conditions are not sufficient unless there is a $y$ such that $h(y) = E[h(Y)]$

Comment: I am not sure why this question is on hold. I still believe it is relevant to this community. I would appreciate if those who vote for closing this question can provide more detail on why this question should be hold.